# get value from url without displaying page in PHP

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite

I need to get a value from a url without the server displaying the page.  For example, if someone goes to:

www.example.com/123456

I want to get "123456" and redirect to www.example.com.

www.example.com/123456 does not exist.

Is this possible with mod rewrite and PHP somehow?

Comment: Not just somehow, it is. Check on mod rewrite documentations and tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example in your .htaccess file (assumes LAMP with mod_rewrite):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

And index.php:

```
<?php
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    // will output: /123456
    echo $url;
?>
```

This setup will redirect all requests which don't point to an actual file or directory to index.php.

Answer (score 1):

You can do simply this:

```
<?php
$data = $_GET['data'];
//Do something with the data
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
?>
```

Comment: This would presume www.example.com/123456 exists.  It doesn't.